# Generate multiple dropbox api access tokens?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I need to give out Dropbox api access tokens and then be able to revoke access at a later time, then I need to be able to generate more access tokens to give out without the user verifying my application again. I thought I would be able to do this using the authorization code multiple times, but it only lets me generate one access token for each authorization code. Does anyone know how to do this without getting more input from the user?

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to do this. To get an access token, the user has to process the app authorization process, which requires their manual intervention. What's the use case here though? There may be an alternate solution to begin with.

Comment: I need to provide new users a way to upload to my dropbox, but I also need a way to revoke access at any time. I don't want to give users my access token, then I couldn't revoke access on a per person basis. I guess I would have to route uploads through a server first and then to dropbox.

Comment: Yes, the Dropbox API isn't designed for this single account use case, so you'll want to send this through a server, given the security issues of distributing access tokens.